# Select distinct of inner object using Linq

Tags: c#, linq

Searched couple of answers in SO but could not figure it out.

Using below classes

```
public class DbTable
{
    public string Database { get; set; }
    public string Schema { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class DbColumn
{
    public DbTable Table { get; set; }
    public string ColumnName { get; set; }
}

List<DbColumn> cols = DataAccess.GetColumns();
```

In `cols` I have many `DbColumn`. Some of them have the same `Table`

I want a list of Table but distinct on Database.Schema.Name

My `cols` looks like:

```
{"Col1", {"MyDB", "dbo", "Product"}     }   
{"Col2", {"MyDB", "dbo", "Product"}     }   
{"Col3", {"MyDB", "Sales", "Customer"}  }   
{"Col4", {"MyDB", "Sales", "Branch"}    }       
{"Col5", {"MyDB", "Sales", "Customer"}  }   
{"Col6", {"MyDB", "Sales", "Branch"}    }
```

What I need is a `List<DbTable>` containing below objects

```
{"MyDB", "dbo", "Product"}      
{"MyDB", "Sales", "Customer"} 
{"MyDB", "Sales", "Branch"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LINQ should be able to do it. You'll need to do a `Select` projection followed by either a group-by or a lookup. Sort of like this:

```
var listOFTables = cols.Select(c => c.Table).ToLookup(k => k.Name, v=> v)
    .Select(k => k.First());
```

This will yield an `IEnumerable<DbTable>` that contains the 3 tables you are expecting.

EDIT: I skipped the part of the question that specified uniquness by **Database**, **Schema**, and Name. This can be easily implemented with a minor change to the above LINQ query:

```
var listOFTables = cols.Select(c => c.Table)
    .ToLookup(k => new {k. Database, k.Schema, k.Name}, v=> v)
    .Select(k => k.First());
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you can accomplish this with a custom comparer. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13332054/1071284).

Comment: This might work but I prefer to have a single LINQ rather than having Comparer. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
  List<DbTable> ListDistinctTable = listcolum.Select(x => new { x.Table.Database, x.Table.Name, x.Table.Schema })
                                                    .Distinct()
                                                    .Select(x => new DbTable() { Database = x.Database, Name = x.Name, Schema = x.Schema })
                                                    .ToList();
```